# Simplifying integer formulas in Z3

Tags: z3

After applying quantifier elimination in Z3 to a linear arithmetic formula `h`, I'm getting a 30-line or so formula. It turns out this formula is equivalent to `h2=And(n>2, i>=0, i<=n-2)`, which I would much prefer as an output.

I tried `ctx-solver-simplify`; I'm getting:
`And(Not(n <= 2), Or(Not(i >= 1), Not(n + -1*i <= 1)), i >= 0)`

Now, `Not(n<=2)` can be more succinctly expressed as `n>=3`, `Not(n + -1*i <= 1)` as `n-i>=2`, and in this formula `i >= 1` is not needed.

`Repeat(Then('nnf','ctx-solver-simplify'))` does a little better (by getting rid of `i>=1`).

Is there a better simplification tactic?

Similarly, is there a tactic that would transform `Or(x==0, x==1, x==2, x==3)` into `And(x>=0,x<=3)`?

Comment: Good question, though I don't think a built-in method will do it. The ctx-solver-simplify method is one of the more aggressive ones and it does not know your intent is to get a conjunction.
Maybe one idea is to simplify formulas modulo a set of templates. You could propose literals extracted from your template space (that you extract from the formula itself) and then extract a conjunction.

Comment: Unfortunately, the expected formula is not necessarily a conjunction. In that particular example, I conjectured that the result should be equivalent to that formula `h2` (`h` comes from a program analysis problem and I had some intuition about what the final result should be like), which I checked with Z3 (`h`⇒`h2` and `h2`⇒`h`), but in general the formula may be more complex. Your idea is interesting, I could, say, conjecture that the formula consists only in a few disjuncts...

Answer (score 1):

My current best solution is to use `Repeat(Then(OrElse('split-clause', 'nnf'), 'propagate-ineqs', 'ctx-solver-simplify'))`, with the latest unstable version of Z3 (where the bug in `ctx-solver-simplify` has been corrected).